# select rows between two dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm trying to do announcement page with asp.net c# and sql server.

In this page i have "popup" field in datebase and if this field checked I want to show this anouncement code in tinybox like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj4Km.png

Its working but I have a problem with dates.

I want to list last "popup" checked field and if this field between the two dates. My sql query looks like this:

```
    Select Top 1 * 
    From duyurlarx 
    Where ([popup] = 1) 
        And tarih 
            BETWEEN convert(date, getdate()) 
                AND DATEADD(day,popupsure,convert(date, getdate()))
```

Field explanation:

```
tarih = date field
popupsure = day count for popup show
```

This means if "tarih" field = 01.02.2014 and "popupsure" field = 3, then this announcement will be shown until 04.02.2014.

However, when I change the date field to 1 or 2 days before, it's not working. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query says
"Give me all the [duyurlarx] with [tarih] between today and [popupsure] days from now"
`|TODAY ---- TARIH ---- TODAY + POPUPSURE|`

It sounds like you want the reverse: all [duyurlarx] where today is between [tarih] and [tarih + popupsure]

`|TARIH ---- TODAY ---- TARIH + POPUPSURE|`

That would correspond to

```
Select Top 1 * 
From duyurlarx 
Where ([popup] = 1) 
    And convert(date, getdate()) 
        BETWEEN tarih 
            AND DATEADD(day, popupsure, tarih)
```

Does that sound right?

Comment: Also, consider adding a computed column on duyurlarx for `DATEADD(DAY, popupsure, tarih)`

Answer (score 0):

You should Cast your fields as Date to have a reliable Date comparison.

```
Select Top 1 * 
    From duyurlarx 
    Where ([popup] = 1) 
        And cast(tarih as Date)
            BETWEEN Cast(GetDate() as Date) 
                AND Cast(DATEADD(day,popupsure,convert(date, getdate())) as Date)
```

Comment: GetDate() returns DateTime, I think

Comment: Isn't he already doing that, essentially?  With `convert(date, getdate())`?

Comment: @RickS that is dangerously wrong after midnight `GETDATE() != '2014-01-31'`.  Maryam is correct.  This was a colossal pain before SQL 2008 introduced the `DATE` type

Answer (score 0):

This is another variant that WILL work

```
Select Top 1 * 
From duyurlarx 
Where ([popup] = 1) 
    And cast(getdate() as date) 
        BETWEEN cast(tarih as date) AND cast(tarih + popupsure as date)
```

You want `CAST AS DATE` because you don't want minutes. And you want to check if today IS between tarih and tarih + popupsure

The single day is added by default when you say `dateField + 1`

Comment: The fact that you have to explain that "The single day is added by default when you say dateField + 1" demonstrates that it is less clear than DATEADD(DAY, [num], [date])

Comment: It is less clear only for those who doesn't know how db server works and, in fact, this is a good item for learning. I can also point that `CAST to DATE` is faster than `convert`

Comment: @İsmailHakkıŞen I understand. It is good answer and will work most of the time but it leaves window for incorrect behavior. My answer closes this window

Comment: The advantage of `CAST` is that it is ANSI compliant. `CAST` is implemented as `CONVERT`: you can see this if you view the execution plan. Please offer proof that it is faster.

Comment: @MarkSowul I was recently benchmarking date comparisons in different formats. CAST was outperforming in SQL server.